# getting this error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" in PHP Laravel 9

Tags: php, laravel

I created a method in my controller of laravel and want to access userid from session

```
static function cartItem()
{
    $userId=Session::get('cart')['id'];
    return Cart::where('user_id', $id)->count();
}
```

but I am getting this error "Trying to access array offset on value of type null" and I don't know why can anyone help me in this

Comment: use `auth()->id`. Cz session is unique

Comment: I made changes to my code according to your suggestion 

static function cartItem()
    {
        $userId=auth()->id;
        return Cart::where('user_id', $userId)->count();
    }

but now I am getting this error "Undefined property: Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager::$id"